# Can't send emails through phpMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Error after clicking submit:

[image: Error after clicking submit]

I have this page on my website with a form, after filling it up and verifying the captcha there's a submit button that sends all the data via email.
I'm using phpMailer but now I keep getting this error.

I tried changing the email provider as with google I may have more problems, but I keep getting the error anyways.

The error links to 'submit.php'

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/functions.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';

session_start();

// Basic check to make sure the form was submitted.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
echo "The form must be submitted with POST data.";
exit();
}

require "appuntamento.php";

// Do some validation, check to make sure the name, email and message are valid.
if (empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    echo "Please complete the CAPTCHA.";
}

$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(CONTACTFORM_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
    $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
    $error = $errors[0];

    $recaptchaErrorMapping = [
        'missing-input-secret' => 'No reCAPTCHA secret key was submitted.',
        'invalid-input-secret' => 'The submitted reCAPTCHA secret key was invalid.',
        'missing-input-response' => 'No reCAPTCHA response was submitted.',
        'invalid-input-response' => 'The submitted reCAPTCHA response was invalid.',
        'bad-request' => 'An unknown error occurred while trying to validate your response.',
        'timeout-or-duplicate' => 'The request is no longer valid. Please try again.',
    ];

    $errorMessage = $recaptchaErrorMapping[$error];
    echo "Please retry the CAPTCHA: ".$errorMessage;
}

// Everything seems OK, time to send the email.

$mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = CONTACTFORM_PHPMAILER_DEBUG_LEVEL;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_HOSTNAME;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_USERNAME;
    $mail->Password = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_PASSWORD;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_ENCRYPTION;
    $mail->Port = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_PORT;

    // Recipients
    $mail->setFrom(CONTACTFORM_FROM_ADDRESS, CONTACTFORM_FROM_NAME);
    $mail->addAddress(CONTACTFORM_TO_ADDRESS, CONTACTFORM_TO_NAME);


    // Content
    $mail->Subject = "Appuntamento presso ".$_POST['Azienda'];
    $mail->Body    = <<<EOT
    Appuntamento presso:  {$_POST['Azienda']},  {$_POST['Citta']}
    il giorno  {$_POST['Richiamare']}
    Riferimento:  {$_POST['Riferimento']}
    Telefono:  {$_POST['Telefono']}
    Email:  {$_POST['Email']}
    Note:  {$_POST['Note']}

EOT;

    $mail->send();
    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "An error occurred while trying to send your message: ". $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

**I have now turned on the display of errors and it gives me an error on line 71.**

E_WARNING Error in file �index.php� at line 71: Undefined array key "Note"

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
            <div class="card mt-5">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 class="card-title">
                        Aggiungi Appuntamento
                    </h1>
                    <p><br></p>
                    <a align="center" href="../elenco.php">Torna all'elenco</a>
                    <p><br></p>
                    <?php
                    if (!empty($success)) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success">Messaggio inviato con successo.</div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                    <?php
                    if (!empty($error)) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger"><?= $error ?></div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                    <?php $Azienda = $_POST['Azienda']; ?>
                    <?php $Tipo = $_POST['Tipo']; ?>
                    <?php $Citta = $_POST['Citta']; ?>
                    <?php $Riferimento = $_POST['Riferimento']; ?>
                    <?php $Email = $_POST['Email']; ?>
                    <?php $Telefono = $_POST['Telefono']; ?>
                    <?php $Note = $_POST['Note']; ?>

                    <form id="target" method="post" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Azienda">Azienda</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Azienda" id="Azienda" class="form-control" 
                                   value="<?php echo $Azienda ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Tipo">Tipo</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Tipo" id="Tipo" class="form-control" 
                                   value="<?php echo $Tipo ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Citta">Indirizzo</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Citta" id="Citta" class="form-control"
                                   value="<?php echo $Citta ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Riferimento">Riferimento</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Riferimento" id="Riferimento" class="form-control"
                                   value="<?php echo $Riferimento ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Telefono">Telefono</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Telefono" id="Telefono" class="form-control"
                                   value="<?php echo $Telefono ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" class="form-control"
                                   value="<?php echo $Email ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="DataAppuntamento">Data Appuntamento</label>
                            <input type="date" name="DataAppuntamento" id="DataAppuntamento" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="DataChiamata">Data Presa Appuntamento</label>
                            <input type="date" name="DataChiamata" id="DataChiamata" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Note">Il Tuo Messaggio</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Note" id="Note" class="form-control" 
                                   value="<?php echo $Note ?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <div align="center" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?= CONTACTFORM_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY ?>"></div>
                        </div>

                        <button name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Invia Email</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check your server/error logs for more info on the 500?

Comment: @brombeer how can I check it?

Comment: You find out where those logs are located (depends on the server you use) and view them, most recent entries are usually at the end

Comment: @brombeer the problem is that I use a free web server and there is zero showing of error logs.

Comment: You call the field `message` but attempt to read it from `$_POST['Note']`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I edited it but it still gives me the same error at line 71

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It seems there is no "Note" key in your POST Request. Please provide your full POST request (Developer Tools in i.e. Chrome)

Comment: Are you sure this problem is directly related to PHPMailer?

Comment: You made an edit after ÁlvaroGonzález warned you, please restart everything from scratch because it sill gives the same error